# Set a jQuery variable from an element class added after page load

Tags: jquery

I know that to run jQuery on an element added after the page load is done using something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.element', function() {
    // code
});
```

However, I don't think that's the solution to my problem.

I have a bunch of textareas on a page, and a modal with some pre-filled content. The user can click a button to copy/paste the information from the modal into a specific textarea, depending on which button they clicked to open the modal.

Open modal code:

```
$('.modal-button').on('click', function() {
    var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
    var height = _window.height();
    $('#'+rel).css('height', height).addClass('active').fadeIn(200);
    // identify textarea
    $(this).parent().find('.wpcf7-textarea').addClass('input-content');
});
```

Copy/paste code:

```
$('.add-to-cv').on('click', function() {
    var content = $(this).closest('.cv-content');
    var input = $('textarea.input-content'); // this bit doesn't work
    input.val(content.text());
    closeModal();
});
```

So the problem is, I'm adding an identifying class to the textarea when the modal is opened, and I want to then select that element in another 'function' using `var input = $('textarea.input-content');`. But of course, there wasn't an element like that on page load so it doesn't find anything.

Any ideas how I can set `.input-content` as a variable when that class has been added after the page load?

**EDIT**

The issue here wasn't with selecting the element with a class added after page load. The issue was with the selector `var content = $(this).closest('.cv-content');`.

RESOLVED.

Comment: `there wasn't an element like that on page load so it doesn't find anything.` That's not the cause of your issue. The DOM is interrogated at the point you clicked the `.add-to-cv` button, so as long as the element exists at that time (and the selector is correct) then your code should work. Are you sure that the `textarea.input-content` still exists after the modal is closed? Is the event on `.add-to-cv` actually triggered? It would help a lot to see a working example of your code in a snippet

Comment: the quest is to figure out, when will `textarea.input-content` exists. You have to make the user click `.modal-button` before `.add-to-cv`.

Comment: Ah, it does look like I've got `textarea.input-content` in the `var` now, apologies. It looks like my problem actually lies with getting the content from the div to place into the textarea (`var content = $(this).closest('.cv-content');`)

Comment: Yes, this was just an issue with a selector getting the content, and is fixed now.